# Does Django ORM map the deleted field before others in the sql where clause?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django ORM will map this queryset

```
TestModel.objects.filter(module="test", deleted=False)
```

to this raw sql:

```
select coll1, coll2, coll3 from test_module where (TestModel.deleted=0 and TestModel.module="test")
```

No matter where you put the "deleted" in the filter paras, it takes the first place it the where clause.

My first guess is that Django put all bool/tinyint field before others, but test shows not. Seems Django just put the field named "deleted" in front of others. Quite odd, but why?

Because I am adding indexes to mysql tables, the order really matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword parameters are handled as a dictionary, which have *arbirtary* ordering. The `deleted` key just happens to come first in that ordering:

```
>>> {'module': 'Test', 'deleted': False}
{'deleted': False, 'module': 'Test'}
```

Ordering in a dictionary is determined by the slot to which they hash in the underlying hash table. A small dictionary starts with 8 slots, and `'deleted'` hashes to slot 0, `'module'` to slot 6:

```
>>> hash('module') % 8
6
>>> hash('deleted') % 8
0
```

In other words, it is entirely a **coincidence** that `'deleted'` is listed first, due to the specific implementation details of Python dictionaries. Django does **not** decide to list that column first on purpose.

The order doesn't matter here, the SQL database doesn't care what comes first either.

Comment: Thanks. But When I filter(module="test", deleted=False, trashed=False), deleted still comes first, even before trashed.

Comment: Why is that a surprise? What makes you think `'trashed'` would be slotted before `'deleted'`? It could have been, but it isn't. There are other keys that *may* be slotted in hash slot `0` too, and then `deleted` might not be first. If you create a larger number of keys, the order could change too.

Comment: There is **nothing in Django** that puts `deleted` first on purpose. It is a *coincidence* that it is listed first only due to the specific implementation details of Python dictionaries.

Comment: I am not saying deleted always comes first, I am trying to find the regulation of it. The order matters because I am adding mysql indexes.

Comment: No, for indexes the order doesn't matter either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-is-arbitrary for more information on dict ordering.